# Is there a way to execute something in android (java) every once in a while?

Tags: java, android

I want a function to be executed once every minute but I´m not sure how to do it.
I have tried this I have read:

I have tried this I have read:

```
public Thread hilo;

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        /
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        
                        System.out.println("Me imprimo cada segundo");tiempo
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        Thread hilo = new Thread(runnable);
        hilo.start();
```

but I get this exception I don´t understand.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.lang.Thread.start()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.tfgsmartwatch.activities.Course.onCreate(Course.java:164)
```

Does anyone know hot to fix it? Or maybe how to do it in a different way? I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Seems you have 2 variables `hilo` (a field and a local variable)... Your code is incomplete (please provide [mvce]).

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell the reason for the `NullPointerException` without the code of the `Activity`.

Apart from that: I would rather use `Timer` and `TimerTask` instead of a `Thread` and `Thread.sleep()`:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-timer-and-timertask

I try to avoid `Thread.sleep()` whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you. I didn´t know about Timer. I will try to do it using that

Answer (score 0):

I think the example is fine; the issue I think, lies in where you are executing those lines. Can you please share with us your complete code?

**Please understand that this is not the best way nor the efficient way to perform something like that; we do have several things in android that allow us to run recurring jobs effectively.**

Here is your code (in Kotlin) to achieve the same thing from an Activity called `MainActivity`:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

  val runnable = Runnable {
    while (true){
      try {

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        System.out.println("Me imprimo cada segundo");
      } catch (e : InterruptedException ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

    val thread = Thread(runnable)
    thread.start()
  }

}
```

And here are the log cats:

https://i.ibb.co/1TQH45h/Screen-Shot-2023-03-20-at-8-03-55-AM.png

Comment: Thank you so much. I will adapt that code to java and use it in my project.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have defined the `hilo` variable twice. I think that's what's causing the error.

FYI, Thread.sleep() isn't very efficient. You can use a Timer instead of Thread.sleep() for your purpose. Here's how you can use Timer:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(60000, new ActionListener() { //60000ms = 1 minute
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Me imprimo cada segundo");
    //Other code
  }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).